# Sentences and Quantifier Rank

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, quantifiers

Suppose we have a (first-order) sentence, having quantifier rank $q$.

How can we prove that it is equivalent or **not** equivalent to a logical sentence of rank $p$, with $p \lt q$?

Say for example:

$$ F := \; \forall x \exists y \,(R(x,y) \lor R(y,x)\;)\lor \exists x R(x,x) $$

How can we prove that it can be, or cannot be, equivalent to *any* sentence (same language) of rank $1$?

Comment: Perhaps I'm mistaken here, but won't that generally depend on the particular sentences involved?

Comment: Absolutely. But I was in search of general guidelines..

Comment: I'm not sure if there are any. This will in general depend both on the value of $p$, if the sentence is existential, universal, etc.

Comment: May I ask you for some reference link?

Comment: Again, I don't know what to refer you to. Maybe you should post a specific example that's troubling you and then we can work it out together?

Comment: Thanks! I edited my original post accordingly..!

Comment: You can see Jouko Vaananen, [Models and Games](https://books.google.it/books?id=uDDDbkfZpIEC&pg=PA81) (2011), **Proposition 4.15** (page 47) and **Proposition 6.3** (page 81).